# 2 different variables poiting to 1 address

Tags: c#, variables, memory-address

I am not that great programmer, but I am trying to make custom Minecraft launcher with C#. Soo I have a class for loading and saving options - works great - but now I have a problem that 2 variables in 1 class are somehow poiting to 1 address. I can choose from 3 different packs, each has individual options. I can load and save RAM, Debug mode, version picking mode and a custom version. But the MODE and VERSION are poiting to the same address, so if I change one, the other changes too, but don't know why, can you help me, please?

What happens when saving options

```
        //Setting stream to beggining
        optstr.Position = 0;
        //Loading options file from the disc
        opt = formatter.Deserialize(optstr) as ObjOptions;
        //Setting version
        opt.version[modpack] = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
        //Setting mode
        if (radioButton1.Checked) opt.mode[modpack] = 0;
        else if (radioButton2.Checked) opt.mode[modpack] = 1;
        else opt.mode[modpack] = 2;
        //Setting debug
        opt.debug[modpack] = debug.Checked;
        //Setting memory
        opt.memory[modpack] = Convert.ToInt16(ram.Text);
        //Setting stream position
        optstr.Position = 0;
        //Writing to file
        formatter.Serialize(optstr, opt);
        //Closing options window
        this.Dispose();
```

ObjOptions class

```
[Serializable]
class ObjOptions
{
    public List<int> version;
    public List<int> mode;
    public List<int> memory;
    public List<bool> debug;
    public ObjOptions(List<int> version, List<int> mode, List<int> memory, List<bool> debug)
    {
        this.version = version;
        this.mode = mode;
        this.memory = memory;
        this.debug = debug;
    }
    public ObjOptions()
    {
        List<int> l1 = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            l1.Add(0);
        List<int> l2 = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            l2.Add(0);
        List<int> l3 = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            l3.Add(1024);
        List<bool> l4 = new List<bool>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            l4.Add(false);
        this.version = l1;
        this.mode = l2;
        this.memory = l3;
        this.debug = l4;
    }
}
```

If you find anything that feels like it can be done better, but serves the same way, do not tell it to me. I just want to know why **opt.mode** and **opt.version** are linked together

Answer (score 2):

Because...

```
this.version = l1;
this.mode = l1;
```

These both assign the same list object reference to the `version` and `mode` fields.  Presumably you meant to assign `hovno` to `this.mode` instead of `l1`?

Comment: Still, does not work. I tough that the problem will be solved like you can see up there (edited my post), still does not work. Even if I make it like this, like the old one or like **new List<int>(l1);** and so on

Comment: @DragonCz Are you deserializing an instance you serialized with the broken code?  If so, those serialized instances are corrupted by the bad code they were constructed with.  Delete them and start over.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was so unaware as I was redoing the code like a million times! Problem is solved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is easy:

```
this.version = l1;
this.mode = l1;
```

You set both `version` and `mode` to the same list. You should do something more like that:

```
this.mode = new List<int>(l1);
```

Comment: your diagnosis of the problem is correct, your proposed solution isn't (or doesn't appear to be).  He has a typo in the variable name, he doesn't want to copy the other list.